# Cannot convert varchar value to int in stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure

```
create procedure [dbo].[CreateNewTicket]
    (@Practice_Id as varchar(40),
    )
  /* insert some rows into TICKET table */
As Begin
   DECLARE @prctid as int

   SELECT @prctid = 'select id from PRACTICE_DETAIL where Practice_Name_Description = ' + @Practice_Id + ';'
 end 
 GO
```

But whenever I am passing value from my C# to stored procedure it is throwing error.

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'select id from
>   PRACTICE_DETAIL where Practice_Name_Description = Bankson PT- Daniel
>   (DBA);' to data type int.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like `id` is a `VARCHAR`.  What is the datatype the column is defined as?

Comment: No my Id column is Int only

Comment: Then why are you trying to assign a `VARCHAR` to it?  `'select id from PRACTICE_DETAIL where Practice_Nanme_Description = ' + @Practice_Id + ';'` is a `VARCHAR`, not a SQL statement.

Comment: @SaurabhMosesRam  Remove the quotes eg: `SELECT @prctid = select id from PRACTICE_DETAIL where Practice_Name_Description = @Practice_Id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
create procedure [dbo].[CreateNewTicket]
(
 @Practice_Id as varchar(40),
)
/* insert some rows into TICKET table */

As Begin
DECLARE @prctid as int
SELECT @prctid = id from PRACTICE_DETAIL where Practice_Name_Description = @Practice_Id;
end 
GO
```

Comment: Thanks it is working fine. now. i did some changes in datatypes and use your select query.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the selected value to integer variable in select statement.

Use the following code:-

```
SELECT @prctid = id from PRACTICE_DETAIL where Practice_Name_Description = @Practice_Id
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jarvis put in his answer, you need to assign an `INT` to the variable `@prctid`.  As your statement is posted, you're trying to assign a `VARCHAR` because of the single quotes:

```
'select id from PRACTICE_DETAIL where Practice_Name_Description = ' + @Practice_Id + ';'
```

This will result in a `VARCHAR`, hence the error.

What you're looking for is:

```
SELECT @prctid = select id from PRACTICE_DETAIL where Practice_Name_Description = @Practice_Id
```

No quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The `id` field must of type `varchar`. That is why you are receiving this error.

You must either return an `int` value or make `@prctid` as `varchar` type to make sure you get a proper value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: my Id column is int only. but for testing i change it to varchar but still it is throwing an error.

Comment: Replace you current query condition with this : `Practice_Name_Description = @Practice_Id`

Answer (score 0):

thank you all. it's working like a charm..

i make the changes like

```
  DECLARE @prctid as int
  SELECT @prctid = id from PRACTICE_DETAIL where Practice_Name_Description = @Practice_Id
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @prctid as varchar(max)

SELECT @prctid = "select id from PRACTICE_DETAIL where Practice_Name_Description =  '" + @Practice_Id + "';"
```

Answer (score -1):

Missing single quote.
Try this.

```
SELECT @prctid = 'select id from PRACTICE_DETAIL where Practice_Name_Description = ''' + @Practice_Id + ''';'
```